# Facebook comments linking only to base url, sub-pages not working

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I've looked and looked and oddly cannot find a solution or direct discussion of what seems like a very common scenario.  I have developed a site with multiple pages and multiple articles per page.  I want the users to be able to register a facebook comment on an individual article.  The url was displaying correcly for each article but the app:id was not registered correctly.  I fixed that and now when a person registers a comment, facebook uses the base url only and picks a random article picture.  Why doesn't it simply register the url I provided?

Here is the code...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="http://www.AmericanWomenMedia.com/fi/<%= Session["PageName"] %>?id=<%= Session["CurrentArticleID"] %>" num_posts="3" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well it looks like my problem probably originates with Godaddy.  I have a 302 redirect error that I think is causing the problem.  What is strange is that the "Recommend" Facebook feature links to the correct article, but the comment feature does not.  In fact, it doesn't work at all now.